# How do I set file permissions correctly for www-data user to access the file?

Tags: file, ubuntu, nginx, permissions, file-permissions

I have a directory on my server

`/home/deploy/rpma/public`

The permissions are

`drwxr-sr-x+  2 www-data www-data  4096 Aug  1 15:16 public`

In this folder I have an index.html file with the following permissions:

`-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   4155 Aug  1 14:32 index.html`

When I run the commmand: `sudo -u www-data cat /home/deploy/rpma/public/index.html`

I get the error

`cat: /home/deploy/rpma/public/index.html: Permission denied`

When trying to access the site I am also getting a 403 forbidden error.

I have tried changing all kinds of file permissions.

`chown -R www-data:www-data /home/deploy/rpma/public`
and
`chmod 755 -R /home/deploy/rpma/public`

Which I believe should set the permissions, but it does not appear to change anything.

The nginx worker process is running under the www-data user.

I have no idea what I could be doing wrong here that is preventing these files from being accessible to the www-data user.

Comment: That user also needs read access to *every* directory in the path. Check the permissions for `deploy` and `rpma`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, this will give both read and write permission of the file to www-data group.

```
sudo chmod g+w /var/www/example.com/project/data/data.json
sudo chown :www-data /var/www/example.com/project/data/data.json
```

And if you want to set only read permission you can replace the `g+w` with `444` in the chmod(change mode) command.

```
sudo chmod 444 /var/www/example.com/project/data/data.json
```